# PropertyTester Does Not Work In Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have the simplest `PropertyTester` possible:

```java
public class MyPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    return false;
}
}
```

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
    <propertyTester
       class="org.acme.project.MyPropertyTester"
       id="org.acme.project.myPropertyTester"
       namespace="org.acme.project"
       properties="property"
       type="java.lang.Object" />
</extension>
```

Which I added to a handler like this:

```xml
 <handler class="org.acme.project.MyHandler" commandId="org.acme.project.myCommand">
    <activeWhen>
       <test property="org.acme.project.property" value="true" />
    </activeWhen>
 </handler>
```

This handler gets called a bunch when clicking inside the main application (namely when changing the focused workbench part). However once I open a wizard or dialog, it does not get called anymore. In fact, it doesn't even get called once for the new window.

Why? How do I write a `PropertyTester` that works reliable on all application windows?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I expected a property tester to be re-evaluated after saving a preference page - which it didn't. My workaround was to explicitly request evaluation. See [here](https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/com.codeaffine.extras.jdt/src/com/codeaffine/extras/jdt/internal/junitstatus/JUnitStatusBarPreferencePage.java#L39) and [here](https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras/blob/master/com.codeaffine.extras.jdt/src/com/codeaffine/extras/jdt/internal/prefs/ExpressionEvaluator.java)

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann So we need to track changes to the focus control and selection (and probably more) ourselfs for all controls on a wizard, so we can request a new evaluation of the property tester at appropriate times?

Comment: From my understanding, commands/handler should work in dialogs as well. But if they don't, then you'd have to update thei enabled/activated state yourself.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann The commands/handlers do work on their own, but since the property tester doesn't work, they are disabled when the new window pops up. Since we want at dynamic contribution to the dialog's menu, it's a bit tricky to request evaluation for all kinds of property testers in all instances the property tester would normally reevaluate.

Answer (score 0):

The property tester is used by the Selection Framework to determine if your handler must be active, if a menu must appear and so on.

It is called when some kind of globally accessible menu must be evaluated like the context menu, the toolbar, the view menu and so on: Every time **you select something different**, Eclipse will **evaluate the new state** and disable/enable/remove entries from all visible menus.

The things that you select in your wizard or dialog are **normally not** propagated to the selection framework (but they could if you want).

It is not clear from your post what you are trying to achieve but keep the rule in mind that the property tester works with elements that you and others have defined in plugin.xml and could possibly appear on any of the available menus in Eclipse.

Comment: This is only partly right. Handler activation is recomputed whenver the evaluation context changes. This is the case when the selection changes, but also on part activation and further events.

Comment: For all intents and purposes this is the correct answer. Switching parts also plays with the selection framework. You mention "further" events. Could you please specify so that we can update the answer?

Comment: IIRC, switching parts does not necessarily cause selection changes - think of a part that isn't a selection provider, or a part activation that does not select anything. Changes to the active shell/worbench window and context(s) also cause evaluation context changes (which recompute handler activation).

Comment: We have a toolbar inside the wizard that can be filled / added to via the _plugin.xml_. Is there a general way to make the wizard behave like the main window and propagate changes of the evaluation context?